# Some type was not declared in this scope event though the include file is included

Tags: c++, building

I am modifying a large project written in C++.
In one particular cpp file I write

```
std::vector<CameraObjectPtr> element;
```

and when I do make I got :

```
In member function .... error: ‘CameraObjectPtr’ was not declared in this scope
          std::vector<CameraObjectPtr> element;
```

Now, `CameraObjectPtr` is a type defined as

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<CameraObject> CameraObjectPtr;
```

in a file called `object.hpp`.

The thing is, I *am including* this file in the original file (the one with the error) by putting in the top

```
#include "base/type/object.hpp"
```

I can't figure it out why it is not finding the type. What can be lacking? Some edition of a make file perhaps?

EDIT:

I figured it out what was the problem.

No matter what you include, *always be careful* about types defined in a different ***namespace***

I modified it to

```
std::vector<anotherNamespace::CameraObjectPtr> element;
```

and now it compiles.

Comment: Could be a gazilion things. MCVE or it didn't happen.

Comment: ^^^ such as... check your include guards, specifically their names, and possible unintended reuse.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Do not edit your question to add an answer to it. If you solved your problem, then create an actual answer and accept it.